# Почему функция "scanf" не работает в си?

Tags: c, ввод, scanf

/*Программа требует от пользователя ввод данных, но эти данные не воспринимаются scanf, выставляются либо минимальные значения, либо нули, уже кучу форумов перерыл в поисках ответа, но так и не нашел его, что делать?
*/

// Геометрическая лаба.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"math.h"
#include"stdio.h" 
#include"Windows.h" 
#include"stdlib.h" 
#include"cstdlib" 
#include"conio.h"

#pragma warning (disable : 4996)
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    float xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc, xd, yd, S, AB, BC, CD, DA, AC, BD;
    
    printf("Введите координаты точек вашей фигуры(по часовой стрелке(A, B, C, D): ");
    scanf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f ", &xa, &ya, &xb, &yb, &xc, &yc, &xd, &yd); 
    printf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f ", &xa, &ya, &xb, &yb, &xc, &yc, &xd, &yd);
    
    AB = sqrt(pow((xb - xa), 2) + pow((yb - ya), 2));
    BC = sqrt(pow((xc - xb), 2) + pow((yc - yb), 2));
    CD = sqrt(pow((xd - xc), 2) + pow((yd - yc), 2));
    DA = sqrt(pow((xa - xd), 2) + pow((ya - yd), 2));
    AC = sqrt(pow((xc - xa), 2) + pow((yc - ya), 2));
    BD = sqrt(pow((xd - xb), 2) + pow((yd - yb), 2));

    if (DA + AB > BD && BC + CD > BD && AB == BC == CD == DA)

    {

        S = 1 / 2 * (AC + CD);

        printf("Площадб ромба S=, %d ", &S);

    }

    else
    {
        printf("Это не ромб, введите координаты заново\n");

        system("pause");

        return 0;
    }
    }
```

//(вот сама программа)

Comment: Пробовали заменить `scanf` на `scanf_s` ?

Comment: printf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f ", &xa, &ya, &xb, &yb, &xc, &yc, &xd, &yd);  - Вы выводите адреса. ИМХО надо printf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f ", xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc, xd, yd); Аналогично в printf("Площадб ромба S=, %d ", &S); Вы выводите адрес переменной S/

Comment: scanf_ s пробовал, но не помогло, комментарий непонятен немного

Comment: @DrunkWithcher, в printf вы выводите **адреса** переменных, а не их значения

Comment: Это я понимаю, но вопрос в другом: почему scanf при вводе данных не воспринимает их? То есть при любых числах ответ один и тот же

Comment: @DrunkWithcher Вы выводите не ответ, а номер ячейки памяти, где он лежит. Выведите содержимое ячейки, а не её номер (адрес). Подробнее описал в своём ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `&` перед именем переменной возвращает адрес в памяти, где хранится эта переменная. Функции `scanf` и другим подобным функциям нужен именно адрес переменной в памяти, поскольку им нужно записывать значение в эту переменную. Единственный способ изменять переменную внутри функции так, чтобы эти изменения были видны снаружи функции - передача в функцию указателя (как это делается в `scanf`) или ссылки на переменную. Функциям вывода, таким как `printf`, не нужно изменять переменную внутри функции. Поэтому они работают с передачей переменной по значению. Оператор взятия адреса (`&`) перед аргументами `printf` не нужен. Если вы всё-таки используете оператор `&` перед аргументами `printf`, то Вы увидите на экране адреса (номера ячеек памяти), где лежат значения, а не сами значения.
Что касается `scanf_s` и других подобных функций. Они делают то же самое, что и обычный `scanf`. Разница только в том, что они требуют указывать размер буфера, что позволяет предотвращать запись данных в память за границей массива.
Что касается вычислений - не возьмусь проверять геометрические формулы. Выведите результат правильно (без `&`). Если он по-прежнему будет неверным, советую просто выводить результаты каждого шага вычислений и сверять с вычисленными вручную данными. Так Вы легко найдёте ошибку.
И расставьте скобки в условии if. Если Вам почему-то не хочется этого делать, почитайте по приоритет операторов и проверьте Ваше условие. Возможно, выражение в условии вычисляется совсем не так, как Вы ожидали.

Answer (score 1):

Так, проблема решилась, во- первых ошибка была в scanf( после %f запятые не нужны), во вторых if надо было переделать вот так  `if ((DA + AB > BD) && (BC + CD > BD) && (AB == BC) && (BC == CD) && (CD == DA) && (DA == AB))`, в третьих амперсанд перед S не нужен, он лишний, спасибо за помощь вам всем))))
, кстати, чуть не забыл `S = (1. / 2.) * (AC * BD);` формулу площади лучше писать вот так.